# Is there Functionality Is there print pdf file multi request C#

Tags: c#, printing, network-printers

Hi All What my scenario is i am trying to print PDF file From console Application its is file watcher program.
Actually i put Xml in particular physical path once the Xml file is created in that folder File watcher action is started.
Read the XML content like printer name and print file. Based on that file sent to printer.
What my problem is, if i give multiple request first one or two file is not sent to printer queue.immediately give another multiple request all the file sent to printer queue.
After 15 or 30 mins the same issue occur first one or two file is not sent to printer.
My code,

```
 public  static void FileWatcherfunction()
        {
            string strprintpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Schedulepath"];
            strprintpath = strprintpath + @"\print";
            //Console.WriteLine("config path:: "+ strprintpath);
            Logger.Log("Print path : "+ strprintpath);
            _fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(strprintpath);
           
            _fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(_fileWatcher_Created);
            _fileWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(_fileWatcher_Deleted);

           }
 private static void _fileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
 {
    Printfile(strPrinterName, strPrintFileName);
 }
  private static void Printfile(String strPrinterName, String strPrintFileName)
   {
    if (File.Exists(strPrintFileName))
                {
                    Process p = new Process();
                    try
                    {
                        
                        strFileType = strPrintFileName.Substring(strPrintFileName.Length - 3);
                        Logger.Log("strFileType:" + strFileType);
                        p.StartInfo.FileName = strPrintFileName;
                        p.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
                        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + strPrinterName + "\"";
                        p.Start();

                        iStartProcId = p.Id;
                        Logger.Log("iStartProcId:"+ iStartProcId) ;
                        p.WaitForExit(15000);
                        Logger.Log("This document has been sent to the printer : " + strPrinterName);
                        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                       // p.WaitForInputIdle();
                        if (strFileType.ToUpper() =="PDF")
                        {
                            Logger.Log("FileType is PDF: ");
                            if (!p.HasExited)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    KillAdobe("AcroRd32", iStartProcId);
                                }
                                catch (Exception killex)
                                {
                                }
                                p.CloseMainWindow();
                                p.Close();
                                
                            }
                           

                        }

                        Logger.Log("Printing process completed");
                    }

                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        KillAdobe("AcroRd32", iStartProcId);
                        Logger.Log("Error: Exception: " + exp.Message);

                    }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are the xml files created and processed? Be aware, `FileSystemWatcher.Created` event doesn't necessarily means, that your xml file is complete. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created?view=net-5.0):

> The OnCreated event is raised as soon as a file is created. If a file is being copied or transferred into a watched directory, the OnCreated event will be raised immediately, followed by one or more OnChanged events.

Some other remarks:

- Get the extension of a filename with [Path.GetExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=net-5.0)
- Compare the extension with [String.Equals(string, string, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-5.0#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_String_System_StringComparison_) and `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`. `String.ToUpper` creates a new string - you don't need it
- 15 seconds to print a document could be sometimes not enough. I would wait longer. Another pitfall could be, that acrord32.exe doesn't quit immediately, it could stay in background waiting for other operations. Perhaps you should never kill the process, you don't examine the exitcode
- Take into account, that on a terminal server you can get a whole bunch of acrord32.exe processes from other sessions too, depending on your privileges. Killing processes by name could be a problem in this case - if your `KillAdobe` method does this
- [Process.CloseMainWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_CloseMainWindow) won't end a process without any user interface or if the process doesn't react to window messages anymore and also could raise an exception
- `Process.HasExited` doesn't necessarily mean, the printing process is done. It could also be, that the newly started application communicates the request to an already running instance and quits before the printing is done
- FileSystemWatcher could also become a problem, see [Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.error?view=net-5.0) event

Comment: Hi Steeve, the XML file Generated in our Application  logic.Once the XML file is generated The file watcher is started.i gave some time delay to read that XML file i file watcher method.